# Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-desktop-full

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04(32 bit), and trying to install ROS fuerte [1], but is giving following error at this step.

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full

---

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-desktop-full

---

Thanks for help

[1]http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50545/unable-to-locate-package-ros-fuerte-desktop-full/) by [ama](https://answers.ros.org/users/3049/ama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-12-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-12-15**:
check this may help you
http://answers.ros.org/question/49906/turtlebot-simulator/?comment=50201#comment-50201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a sytax error in the fuerte.rosdistro file which crashed the variant metapackage generation.  The error was fixed last night and the script was made robust to the error as well.  This should be fixed now.  Make sure to apt-get update.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1